# Is it correct O(n!)=O((n+1)!)?

Tags: complexity-theory

Assuming `f(n)=n!`, I can prove that for `C=1` and `n_0=1` Big-oh of `f(n) = O(n!)`.

However, to prove RHS I found `C>=1/n & n_0=0`.

Can `C` be in terms of `n`?

Comment: I think you need to be more clear in your question. What is `C`? what is `n_0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly the case that n! = O((n+1)!), and yes, most any choice of the constant c should work since (n+1)! grows faster than n! by a factor of (n+1).

Note that asking where n! = O((n+1)!) is a different question (strictly speaking) from asking whether O(n!) = O((n+1)!), and in this case the answers are different. The latter of these can be interpreted to mean, "Is the set of all functions which are bounded by above by n! the same as the set of all functions bounded from above by (n+1)!?" That is not true since you can show there is no constant c greater than (n+1).